# Displaying the API response in a new html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to use the DATA FROM THE **API RESPONSE**. I want my React App to Open a new Window, Page, or whatever other than the same page. Then display the Data it gets from this **API**. *Please it is for the best if you use examples to help junior developers learn. We all know technical terminology is hard than writing actual code.*

If you would like to test the API in POSTMAN:

TOKEN: fb83b937-2739-3d6e-9519-09387b92dfae
API: https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/

Please use this in your body:

```
{
  "transactionReference": "string",
  "paymentMethod": "CreditCard",
  "checkoutOrderUrl": "http://www.test.com/",
  "user": {
    "name": "string",
    "msisdn": "+27610983142",
    "email": "test@test.com"  },
  "payementMethodDetail": {
    "RedirectUrl": "http://www.test.com",
    "PurchaseEventWebhookUrl": "http://www.test.com"  },
  "bundle": [
    {
      "ProductCode": "317",
      "Amount": 5000,
      "CurrencyCode": "ZAR",
      "Quantity": 1    }
  ]
}
```

This is my current solution:
I am doing the POST request when a user clicks Pay Now. Only when the user does that, is when I need to display a loading message and show the results in a new window/page/path.

```
  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const token = "fb83b937-2739-3d6e-9519-09387b92dfae";
    const data = {
      transactionReference: "string",
      paymentMethod: "CreditCard",
      checkoutOrderUrl: "http://www.test.com/",
      user: {
        name: name, 
        msisdn: phone, 
        email: email, 
      },
      payementMethodDetail: {
        RedirectUrl: "http://www.test.com",
        PurchaseEventWebhookUrl: "http://www.test.com",
      },

      bundle: cart.map((item) => ({
        ProductCode: `${item.ProductCode}`,
        Amount: item.amount,
        CurrencyCode: item.currencyCode,
        Quantity: item.quantity,
      })),
    };
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    };
    await fetch(
      "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.json(),
      console.log("Data Sent")
      )
      .then((res) => { 
        Navigate(<Payment/>, {state: res})
      });
  };
```

Thank you to those who are going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

From what I can understand of your question you are wanting to navigate to a route rendering the `Payment` component with the specified response payload. The issue is that you can't return a `Navigate` component from a callback function like this and expect it to effect any change in the UI. The `Navigate` component either needs to be rendered as part of the component result, or an imperative navigation action.

## Solution

Import and use the `useNavigate` hook to access the `navigate` function and issue an imperative navigation with the POST response data in route state.

Example:

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const handleSubmit = async () => {
  ...
  await fetch(
    "https://api.flash-internal.flash-group.com/ecommerceManagement/1.0.0/api/checkout/",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((payment) => { 
      navigate("/confirmation", { state: { payment } });
    });
};
```

Create a route rendering the `Payment` component:

```
<Routes>
  ... other routes ...
  <Route path="/confirmation" element={<Payment />} />
  ...
</Routes>
```

In the `Payment` component use the `useLocation` hook to access the passed route state.

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const Payment = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { payment } = state || {};

  ...
};
```